# Re-stain slice using a different secondary antibody?

Tags: lab-techniques, antibody, protocol, fluorescent-microscopy, staining

I stained a free-floating ~300uM brian slice using 4 different 1º antibodies (rabbit, chick, mouse, rat).

For the mouse primary, I mistakenly used an Alexa-350 secondary, when I should have used 594.

The microscope we have in lab cannot detect the 350 fluorophore, so I'm wondering if I can re-stain the slice with the anti-mouse 594 secondary.

Thanks for your advice !

[cross-posted in [reddit/labrats]](https://www.reddit.com/r/labrats/comments/bcupgd/restain_slice_using_a_different_secondary_antibody/)

Comment: Are they the same clone? You might have blocked all the binding sites so you'll get a poor/no/noisy signal with the 594.

Comment: Thanks for your input ! They are both Alexa conjugated anti-mouse secondaries, so I'm guessing they use the same clone to make them. (?)